# Predefined define for 64 bit environment?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, 64-bit, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

is there a predefined constant available in VS2010 that specifies code is compiled for Windows 64 bit? Currently I would check if a specific type has a length of 4 or 8 bits but I wonder if there is a more elegant way to find this out?

Thanks!

Comment: Native C/C++...did not know .NET / C# has a preprocessor...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx

Comment: .net has #define :-[

Comment: rhapsodyn: Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just more convenient (than comment) for readers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx